# Stored proc to update a table from using data stored in a file on network

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table in a database that holds the number of a countries credit card transactions broken out in 10 minute intervals. I have a separate process which generates Excel files for updated transaction counts every 10 minutes. I want to create a stored procedure that reads the data in from these network folders every 10 minutes, and I want to compare a countries most recent 10 minute period to its prior 10 minute period. If it increases by more than 10 percent, it should alert a handful of people with an email alert. I know that I will need a stored procedure to append this data to the current transaction table to the database, but I was wondering if SQL Server Job Agent is to be used when attempting to read in this file every 10 minutes, and then again when the potential alert is sent out?

Comment: If you are reading from the file system your best bet is to write your own service which reads the files and inserts them into the database. Doing that within the database is the wrong place.

Comment: If the data in the excel files originates in the server instance, why does the server instance need to read the files for data it already contains? Are you over-complicating this?